# Post closed as duplicate, but there is a better original

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

My question was recently closed as a duplicate. The linked question does not actually contain an answer to my question, though. However, I found another question that contains a (better) answer to my question.

How to remove the wrong link and add the right link?

Example: [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1412218/windows-file-type-association-open-bat-in-same-powershell-window) closed as a duplicate of [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1110793/associate-sh-scripts-to-windows-bash) but a better original is [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/437790/run-python-scripts-in-powershell-directly?rq=1).

Comment: Maybe you should ask this on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com)?

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ The question is general enough to be asked here.

Comment: I made a quite drastic change to your question, because (as @πάντα said) this question seems to be general enough to be asked here but the previous wording sounded IMHO a bit more to be about a specific question, which could have resulted in downvoting/closing. Feel free to roll back my edit, if you think it is unhelpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to remove the wrong link and add the right link?

You can't unless you have a gold badge for one of the tags applied to the question.

You might ping a close voter who has that privilege to add your link (and maybe remove the original one).

Another option is to ask for that at the site specific Meta site.

---

You can also edit your question and add the link to the duplicate you found yourself, along with a description why that works better for you than the originally chosen duplicate.

The latter method would have the advantage that the question is bumped to the home page (active tab) of the site, and might receive more attention from users who could add or replace the duplicate link.

Comment: Moderators can do this too, so depending from the site, you might have success flagging your post for moderator attention (*flag* link).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a gold tag badge for any of the question's tags, there's no way for you to directly change what the question's closed as a duplicate of.

You can edit your question to explain why it is not a duplicate of what it was closed of, but is a duplicate of a different question. From there, a gold tag badger can edit the duplicate list or the question can go through the whole reopen-then-close-again process.

Another option is to start a discussion on the relevant per-site meta asking for the question to be reopened and closed again. Use the tags [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and either [reopen-request](/questions/tagged/reopen-request) or [reopen-closed](/questions/tagged/reopen-closed) depending on the site.

Finally, if you have the [view close votes privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), you can also vote to reopen your own question. If you have [cast close & reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you can do this for other people's questions as well.